# Getting unknown attribute error in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on a project which I saw in a video tutorial. But when I write `app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"` to link customized menu, I have a problem. It is not work properly. This is my code error image.

[image: error code image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your main xml element

Comment: In this xml file? instead xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" this?

Comment: no, they are not the same they should be both there, you can put xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" bellow  xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: work 100% thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using drawer  layout at your root layout. If that is the case then Add below line of code to your drawer layout

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```